# Intel "Inside everywhere"

Tags: discussion

Unusual question came up on our website:

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/498/tempest-proof-pc-notebook

What do you think about questions like this? Can it be taken seriously?

Comment: What's he even asking for? A faraday-cage computer case?

Comment: Something like this (among others).

Comment: First time I've read a question on SE that legitimately made me uncomfortable.

Comment: An author has improved the question a little bit: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/498/tempest-proof-pc-notebook?noredirect=1#comment1070_498 What else do we except to reopen this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asking for unusual equipment (eg. a CIA-resistant computer) should be fine, as long as you can clearly define what it is you're looking for.  In this case, I think the question should be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 5):

> Can it be taken seriously?

Some people might be able to. I can't.

Speaking for this specific question... I don't know what he wants. A computer? A computer case? That is also a faraday cage? A computer... without a... processor? He hasn't defined what 'TEMPEST-proof' means. I've voted to close it as unclear.

---

In general, though, if someone can clearly define their requirements, even if it's a tinfoil-hat person, I think the question should be okay. If he'd asked for a 'computer inside a faraday cage that runs *OS* and doesn't have a processor made by *company* that has at least *x* GB RAM and such'... then fine. I'd be inclined to say that's on topic.

Comment: TEMPEST-proof, presumably means that the device doesn't leak radio or  electronic signals, vibrations or sounds. TEMPEST is an NSA and NATO certification for both spying and shielding against such unintentional electronic leaks. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_%28codename%29) has a decent article on it.